# Suddenly no internet connection Ubuntu 21.04

Tags: networking, internet, 21.04

So until yesterday my internet was just working fine, today it doesn't anymore. Nothing has changed in terms of updates or configuration since then.

The PC is still connected to the router. I can ping the router at 192.168.178.1 and even log in to the settings.
The router is also connected to the internet, all other computers in the house can access the internet.

I can also ping any device that is in the local network.

I.e. ping -c 2 192.168.178.43 works.

But I cannot seem to connect to any outside IP whatsoever.

When doing ping -c 2 1.1.1.1 or ping -c 2 8.8.8.8 I always get 100% package loss.

Could there be some cached settings perhaps that are suddenly not allowing my router to process the request? Or perhaps my router can't send back any information to my PC anymore?

These are all shots in the dark, as I am relatively new to using Linux, and the problem just mysteriously appeared. No settings have been altered and it was working fine before.

I'd be happy to hear some ideas on how to fix this. I'd rather not re-install the whole system.

Comment: Have you rebooted the router yet? That should be the first troubleshooting step.

Comment: Done that. Could it be that my VPN program has changed something? I read something about a resolv.conf file, is there a way to restore this to the system defaults?

Comment: That information should be in the question itself.

Comment: Ok, weird, beforehand I could not launch my VPN client. Now after a couple of reboots I managed to start the VPN Client, it notified me of "Network Issues". After connecting and disconnecting to the VPN Server my original IP was shown again. And the internet is working now.
Perhaps it had something to do with the VPNs "kill switch" feature. It states that on VPN connection drop it cuts the internet to prevent IP leak.

Perhaps this can help others who have a similar problem.

Comment: If you understand and can articulate the technical reason for your problem, you should post an answer.  If all you did was reboot and reconnect, then this describes a problem that can't be reproduced, that seemingly went away on its own or was only relevant to a very specific period of time. It would be off-topic as it's unlikely to help future readers.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you've fixed this now. I've just had the same problem. i.e. I Could ping local IPs, but not 1.1.1.1
`sudo ip addr flush eth0` then a reboot fixed my problem

Answer (score 0):

To reply to
betatester988 Jul 19 at 16:53.
I also found that protonvpn was stopping all my connections even when switched off.
nmcli connection show - - active
Output showed ipv6leak-protection which I deleted using nmcli connection delete [name of connection]

I don't know if I needed to uninstall and remove old files as per proton vpn instructions but I did.
Connection to Internet now restored and with protonvpn reinstalled.